# JPA.withTransaction executing other controllers method error: Global.java:39: error: 'void' type not allowed here

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, akka, actor

I am trying to execute some db insert/update queries in some time intervals.

To achive this I'decided to use Playframework built in Akka Actor system.

I have my class with method:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public void onStart(Application application) {
        Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
             Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), // start task delay
             Duration.create(24, TimeUnit.HOURS), // between task instance delay
             //Duration.create(24, TimeUnit.HOURS), // between task instance delay
                  new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                        JPA.withTransaction(
                            ImportCrmData.start()
                        );
                      }
                  },
                  Akka.system().dispatcher()
        );
```

And the method that is called by the actor system:

```
public class ImportCrmData extends Controller {
    @Transactional
    public static void start() {
        List<Customer> customersToUpdate = CustomerCRM.importCrmData();
        for(Customer c: customersToUpdate) {
            c.toDataBase();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on compile:

```
[error] app/modules/common/app/Global.java:39: error: 'void' type not allowed here ImportCrmData.start()
```

I understand that the problem occurs cause JPA.withTransaction() demand me to return from `ImportCrmData.start()` return `Callback0` or `Function0<>`, but I dont know how to do it.

My method is just doing `this.persist`. Why should I even return something from that?

Answer (score 1):

`ImportCrmData` is a [controller](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaActions) thus it must return a valid http response (a result). A typical use case:

```
public class CustomerController extends Controller {

    public static Result getCustomers() {
        List<Customer> customers = CustomerService.getCustomers();
        return ok(Json.toJson(customers));
    }

}
```

Above example consists of controller which is an entry point to your application and reacts with client requests. `CustomerService` encapsulates logic related to getting customers. `ok(...)` returns an implementation of `Result` - a valid http response with code 200 and in above scenario, json body. It is implemented in `Controller` base class. Next your controller can be mapped in `routes` file to a url like so:

```
GET /customers controller.CustomerController.getCustomers
```

Applying above `pattern` you should have:

- CrmController - entry point
- CrmService - actual business logic

This separation allows using your `CrmService` in `Global` class, as well as in `Controller` layer without duplicating logic. Mind this is just a suggestion.

Comment: I've move my ImportCrmData into services. Itsnt extends play controller class anymore. Error stil occur